# What does it take to get people's attention to answer a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, downvotes

Like seriously, I've been struggling with some issues for a long time and whenever I post my problem I don't get enough answers or NO answers at all!!

Some would go far and downvote my question.. Which is kinda frustrating 'cause SO is better known as a platform where people can help each other and also learn from their mistakes. But unfortunately I've been seriously disappointed..

I don't know whether my questions are too difficult to answer or need more clarifications (although I do provide enough information concerning my problem).. But it's always the same story.

So what does it take to get people answer our questions??!

Comment: Write a good question.  The downvotes are signs that the posts you've created aren't useful or clear.

Comment: Your [most recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942055/login-method-using-c-sharp-in-wcf-webservice-and-getting-data-based-on-users-cr) is scarily long. You're asking a lot of things. Perhaps try and be more focused on *one specific problem*. A lot of your questions are lengthy but not detailed. And some of the [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386876/how-to-connect-a-postgresql-database-with-a-sencha-touch-mobile-app#comment46952204_29386876) you've posted aren't really fostering a good feeling from you.

Comment: Well, now you have Meta's attention, although it may not be the attention you're looking for

Comment: Interesting, because It also works the other way. I answer many questions and wonder what it takes for the answer to be noticed.  :- ) There must be plenty of people who ask, wait 2 minutes for an answer and give up. One questioner **demanded** that we write him a working answer within the next 2 hours. He never accepted the answer.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Like the downvotes I got now for this question :) ? What's so unclear about it? I only needed some answers. And if one of my questions seemed unclear I truly wish people to ask me to clarify it more! Don't u think it's better than just downvoting it ? We all make mistakes.

Comment: @TZHX Wow, so u noticed my comments and not the other guy's first comments ? If I'm wrong or unclear I'd like to be pointed that out instead of just being upvoted without knowing where I've missed. Some people r greatly kind and helpful but some r just not so much. So instead of making fun of people or telling them to go google the answer (the case of that guy's comment which u haven't notice maybe) it would've been much better to tell me that my question is unclear or whatever the problem is :)

Comment: @GeoSal on the meta, downvote also mean disagreement.  And since the points don't matter, people tend to be much more prone to voting.  Also, your post is borderline rant, which turns people off.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Oh I've noticed that, it's funny how I got downvoted for all my previous unnoticed questions now just after posting this question here in Meta. Could u explain to me why is this happening :)? Just because I thought I'd geniunely ask this question here to figure out what could be wrong and how can I get people to answer my questions. And in the end, this is what I get..

Comment: @GeoSal I don't care about the other guys comments. I was referring to how **you** came across, and was trying to give some constructive feedback. That you are taking things so personally suggests you don't have a good grasp of what this site is meant to be about. Also, phrases like "Like seriously", multiple exclamation marks, and telling us how disappointed you are in the community does not come across as someone sincerely trying to better themselves. Finally, "please go look at my questions, you massive disappointments" will lead to people looking at your questions while biased against you.

Comment: @BrianTompsett I understand u, it goes both ways.. But to be honest it took weeks for a question to get answers.. some would get downvoted, and no answer at all.. I just wish people would interact and give their feedback on other people's mistakes and pointing them into the right track, instead of just downvoting questions or answers with no feedback..

Comment: @TZHX Everyone has the right to think whatever they want, I don't care about that neither! I had no intention whatsoever to attack someone or the community as u r referring to. My question was simple and what I was hoping to get from it is some feedbacks, since the main request from my post is for people to give a feedback and answer questions even if they seem to be unclear, at least let the other know what's wrong with it or if there's any way to reformulate the question, let them know, instead of just downvoting it.. Thanks though for ur feedback.

Comment: @GeoSal Looks like you've been hit by the meta-effect now, and some of your questions were even downvoted more. I'd seriously recommend to read those linked articles from my answer, and improve your questions towards the policies described there. Good luck!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I noticed that and actually I'm kinda shocked by it.. It's just so unfair 'cause all what I wanted was some feedbacks on this issue since I've been struggling for quite some time.. Thanks a lot though for ur answer, really appreciate it and good luck to u too :)

Comment: Note that "look, I know how to implement SQL injection" (which is how your linked question feels) is not the best sample one can come up with...

Comment: @Gisel use proper spelling and punctuation. people at SO absoultely hate it when you say "u" and "ur". Some of your questions beong on code review.

Answer (score 10):

Not every question in the world have an answer. To get the best responses, your question should be [good](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

- Write a title that summarizes the specific problem
- Introduce the problem before you post any code
- Help others reproduce the problem
- Include all relevant tags
- Proof-read before posting!
- ...

If you feel your posts meet the standards, you can [raise a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) when you'll have the minimal reputation needed (awarded at 75 reputation).

Comment: Thank u for the feedback :) !!

Comment: @GeoSal I'm glad it helped, consider downvotes as a constructive criticism and always aim to better posts, like we all do.

Answer (score 10):

> *"SO is better known as a platform where people can help each other"*

You may have approached the site with a wrong attitude, it's not primarily about you getting helped, but we want to have questions (and answers) that are suitable to help anyone in future research.

I have checked some of your unanswered questions, which describe very localized problems, or are just too vague about the exact problem.

You may want to read these articles from the help center to improve your questions

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank u for the feedback :)! Sorry I can't upvote ur answer because my reputation went down because of this question..